# ERROR 11664 --- [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport : HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful

Tags: spring, hibernate, web-services, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a small project of mine working, regarding the implementation of a process via WebServices.
Problem is: I dont even get to that point because I seem to hit trouble when booting Spring.
Spring is in fact booting but I cant get hibernate working ( atleast I think the problem lies with hibernate? ).

My ErrorLog: [onPasteBin](http://pastebin.com/u9WdtrRA)

My application.properties:

```js
#New
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create




#Old
# Thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false

# Database
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/igt
db.username: root
db.password: passwort



# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.entities
```

And my DatabaseConfig.java:

```js
package com.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

I dont think the Application.java is really relevant to this, but here it is nonetheless:

```js
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Maybe the Project Structure is helpful: 
[Screenshot of the ProjectStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBIAW.jpg)

Thanks very much in advance =)

Comment: Looks like you db is not started: `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Comment: Shouldn't Springboot do that for me? And how could I encourage Sprinboot to do that, if its not starting?

Comment: Worked around it, by creating the DB manually.